# Can custom converter accept Objects other than String as parameter

Tags: java, parameters, converters, javabeans, dozer

I want to pass a Map object to a custom converter as custom parameter.

```
<class-a>SourceBom</class-a>
      <class-b>TargetBom</class-b>
        <field custom-converter="myCustomConverter"  custom-converter-param="mapObject">
             <a > address.HouseNo</a> 
             <b> user.home.address.houseNo</b> 
        </field>
```

The CustomConverter needs the map object values (that was created outside this mapping )for the conversion, Does dozer provides a way to  sent non String Objects as customParameter.

Comment: Hi @Malathi if this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark and up-voting it. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, Dozer doesn't provide a way to handle non String Objects as parameters. If you look at the [documentation](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/customconverter.html), the override method specifically sets the parameter as a String.

The intention of the parameter was to make it easy for the Converter to distinguish between lots of similar types of conversions, not actually carry important data (in this case your Map Object). I'm sure it's possible to recreate your converter in a way that doesn't require the Map as a parameter.

You could post another question for that if you wish and I'll answer it.